# What typically happens to H2 molecules released into atmosphere (with no spark source)?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, hydrogen, photochemistry, reactivity

I'm wondering what happens when $\ce{H2}$ leaks from say a transmission pipe in an unenclosed area. No immediate source of ignition, I know it rises more quickly than helium (x2 I believe) and dissipates in concentration quickly but does it react with gases in atmosphere to form methane or other compounds?

Short of ignition and burning causing more $\ce{H2}$ to dissociate what can happen, especially in upper atmosphere with more UV and so on. Methane has reaction in the upper atmosphere giving it a half life of ~7 years for example.

> The covalent radius of a neutral hydrogen atom is 0.0371 nm, smaller
>   than that of any other element. Because small atoms can come very
>   close to each other, they tend to form strong covalent bonds. As a
>   result, the bond dissociation enthalpy for the $\ce{H-H}$ bond is relatively
>   large (435 kJ/mol). $\ce{H2}$ therefore tends to be unreactive at room
>   temperature. In the presence of a spark, however, a fraction of the $\ce{H2}$ molecules dissociate to form hydrogen atoms that are highly reactive. Source: [chemed.chem.purdue.edu](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch10/hydrogen.php)

Comment: Hmm, UV can readily dissociate $\ce{Cl2}$, but I'm not really sure about hydrogen gas. It's known to be reacting vigorously, but only if some good amount of activation energy is provided.

Comment: interesting, activation energy in the form of radiation or kinetic agitation?

Comment: Activation energy can be kinetic or potential. Basically, you need the reacting species with correct orientation and enough energy to collide. See [collision theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_theory) and [The Arrhenius Law](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Kinetics/Modeling_Reaction_Kinetics/Temperature_Dependence_of_Reaction_Rates/The_Arrhenius_Law/The_Arrhenius_Law%3A_Activation_Energies).

Answer (score 3):

The most common, reactive stuff in the atmosphere are $\ce{-OH}$ radicals [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxyl_radical#Importance_in_Earth.27s_atmosphere). So I guess they're the natural antagonist for $\ce{H2}$ molecules.

Btw., as soon as it's diluted in the surrounding air, it will no longer rise. Only bulk masses have buoyancy. The g gradient in the atmosphere is much too small to separate gases.

In the end, hydrogen however *does* diffuse upwards and is ultimately lost into space. Hydrogen and helium are light enough to be able to reach escape velocity in the upper atmosphere.

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation " latex="" ‎at="" ‎chemistry.se""="), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/443/should-‎we-correct-math-formatting) and [this ‎one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111/formatting-sandbox-please-test-‎stuff-here) on how to make your future posts better.‎ || I like the "prey" analogy, but I believe the $\ce{H2}$ will be the prey and hydroxide anions the predator.

Comment: Your point about buoancy is not really true on geologic time scales.   Early in Earth's history, large amounts of hydrogen (H2) gas were lost to space.  The process continues today albeit at far lower rates.  Even so, the rate of H2 loss to space far larger than say N2 or O2 loss to space.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_escape - Yeah hydrogen and helium do escape albeit in little amounts

Comment: Has nothing to do with buoancy. The speed of H2 molecules( or He) in the upper atmosphere is above the escape velocity. He and H2 have a net flow upwards because of diffusion in the ensuing concentration gradient.

Comment: methane rises to the upper atmosphere where it decays and it is heavier than H2 (obv.). does buoyancy apply to gases in air? (As opposed to gases contained in solids on or in water).

Comment: No, it just diffuses up there. As it can't diffuse back (it's destroyed up there), there is a net flow upwards. An entropy gradient drives it up, not one in potential energy.

Comment: Hydrogen won't last long in a thunderstorm either.  Lightning discharges break up the molecules or produce hydroxyl radicals that later eat the hydrogen.